# Combining rows with repeated ids by means in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I would like to combine the following dataframe where repeated ids will be **combined together by the mean values of repeated observation.**

```
id     V1      V2
AA  21.76410    1       
BB  25.57568    0       
BB  20.91222    0       
CC  21.71828    1       
CC  22.89878    1       
FF  22.20535    0
```

```
structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("AA", 
"BB", "CC", "FF"), class = "factor"), V1 = c(21.7640981693372, 
25.575675904744, 20.9122208946358, 21.7182828011676, 22.8987775530191, 
22.2053520672232), V2 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

After data reduction by mean, it should like this-

```
id     V1       V2
AA  21.76410    1       
BB  23.24395    0   # mean reduction for BB in V1 and V2    
CC  22.30853    1   # same as above 
FF  22.20535    0
```

```
structure(list(id = structure(1:4, .Label = c("AA", "BB", "CC", 
"FF"), class = "factor"), V1 = c(21.7641, 23.24395, 22.30853, 
22.20535), V2 = c(1, 0, 1, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

How can I do that in R?
Any package function or custom function code you want to share with me would be of great help.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `aggregate(.~ id, df1, mean)`

Answer (score 4):

With `base R`, it can be done with `aggregate`

```
aggregate(.~ id, df1, mean)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(V1 = ifelse(n() > 1, mean(V1), V1)) %>%
  unique()

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   id [4]
#   id       V1    V2
#<fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 AA     21.8     1
#2 BB     23.2     0
#3 CC     22.3     1
#4 FF     22.2     0
```

Comment: Or just `df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise_all(mean)`.

Comment: @ulfelder Nice. Wasn't familiar with `summarise_all`. Thanks!

Comment: @hulk I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Another way of using `aggregate` from base R

```
dfout <- aggregate(df[-1],df[1],FUN = mean)
```

such that

```
> dfout
  id       V1 V2
1 AA 21.76410  1
2 BB 23.24395  0
3 CC 22.30853  1
4 FF 22.20535  0
```